# SSH with subprocess

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to make a program that will automatically add a proxy and the whitelists to my settings in Nutanix, so far I am able to get the proxy to add, but I am unable to get the whitelists to add.
The whitelist ip's are being ran in a single line. the "\n" does not work on them. Below is my code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
add_whitelists = "ncli http-proxy add-to-whitelist target-type=IPV4_ADDRESS target="
whitelist_Ip = ["192.168.1.22", "192.168.1.23"]
login = "nutanix@192.168.1.50"
add_pxy = "ncli http-proxy add name=NPX5-proxy address=proxy.npx5.local port=8080 proxy-types=HTTPS"
list_proxy = "ncli http-proxy get-whitelist"
nl = '\n'
#ssh connection
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-i .ssh/id_rsa", login],
                        stdin =subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        universal_newlines=True,
                        bufsize=0)

# Send ssh commands to stdin
ssh.stdin.write(add_pxy + "\n")
for ip in whitelist_Ip:
    ssh.stdin.write(add_whitelists + ip + "\n")
ssh.stdin.close()
# Fetch output
for line in ssh.stdout:
    if line == "END\n":
        break
    print(line,end="")
```

Thanks.

Comment: To offer a suggestion -- tell it to ssh into a Linux machine and run `cat >stdin-test.txt` as the primary command, then inspect that file later. The claim that `\n` isn't being sent is implausible -- it bears more evidence about how you're testing included in the question.

Comment: That said, I would consider looking into whether the remote system expects CRLF instead of just CRs, or if it expects the user to wait to be returned to a prompt before sending the next command.

Comment: ...if that latter issue (not working properly unless future commands are delayed until the prior command is finished) is the case, [`pxssh`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html) is your friend, as a tool that can wait for a prompt to be printed before sending content.

Comment: ...that said, if that _is_ your problem, you should be able to reproduce it without Python being involved at all. Does `ssh yourhost <<EOF`, followed by the commands you want to run, followed by `EOF`, work on the command line when run by bash? (If it doesn't, we've ruled out anything Python-specific, and made things like the timing issues described above more likely).

Comment: ^ This. Consider using existing libraries that take care of most of the connection stuff for you. Not only is it easier to get working but you will probably get lots of side-benefits. pxssh is a nice suggestion and so are [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko), [spur](https://github.com/mwilliamson/spur.py), [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).